# What is difference between File file = new File() and File file = new File.Paths.get().toFile()?

Tags: java, file, io, path

Is any difference? First solution has "new" and second hasn't. I see only this difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `new File` in this case. 
(Also your second possibility will not work the way you use it here).

There are other cases where you for example only have a `Path` object and you'd like to convert it into a File. Then you would use the `toFile` method on the Path-Object to get a `File` back.

In your case you access the File, convert it into a Path and then back into a File, which isn't necessary at all.

For example if you have a Path and want the file from it:

```
//existing Path object
void receivePath(Path path) {
  File = path.toFile();
}
```